# Javascript string conflict

Tags: javascript

```
fullList.innerHTML = fullList.innerHTML + "<li class='Item show'><a class='Link' onclick='console.log('hello')'>" + uniqueSummonerNameList[foo].toString()+ "</a></li>"
```

That is my code. As you can see, I am trying to do stuff to an HTML file that I do not have access to. This is done through developer console/chrome extension. I am trying to make the anchor tag run javascript onclick, but I have not been able to solve this string problem for the past hour. Javascript will make the innerHTML

```
onclick='console.log('
```

instead of

```
onclick='console.log('hello')
```

I basically want to do stuff with strings in my final code, but I can't get a simple function to work with onclick.

Comment: use `console.log(\"hello\")` instead of `console.log('hello')`

Comment: or `onclick="console.log('hello')"`

Comment: Putting that much raw HTML in a string with the purpose of echoing it is usually an invitation for errors which the IDE cannot warn you about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fullList.innerHTML = fullList.innerHTML + "<li class='Item show'><a class='Link' onclick=\"console.log('hello')\">" + uniqueSummonerNameList[foo].toString()+ "</a></li>"
```

Comment: consider explaining your answer - show the differences between your version and the original.

Comment: @ ADyson My version :  `onclick=\"console.log('hello')\"` and original : `onclick='console.log('hello')'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
'<li class="Item show"><a class="Link" onclick="console.log(\'hello\')">' + uniqueSummonerNameList[foo].toString() + '</a></li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me

```
"<li class='Item show'><a class='Link' onclick='console.log(\"hello\")'>click</a></li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with ES6 then you can use back-tick(``)

```
fullList.innerHTML = `${fullList.innerHTML}<li class='Item show'><a class='Link' onclick="console.log('hello')">${uniqueSummonerNameList[foo].toString()}</a></li>`
```

See below link for more about template literals:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals